# How do I get the child folder name of the path besides these methods?

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems, python-os, pathlib

Of the given path like "level1/level2/level3/", I'd like pass it through some operation and get the result like "level3/". So I made two trials like these:

TRIAL 1:
After finding `parent` property within the Path object, I looked for something close to a `child` property, but could not.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path("level1/level2/level3/")
>>> path.parent
WindowsPath('level1/level2')
>>> str(path.parent)
'level1\\level2'
```

TRIAL 2: I used the `os` module like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename("level1/level2/level3/".strip("/")) + "/"
'level3/'
```

Is there an alternative to TRIAL 2, or can I make something work within TRIAL 1 from the `pathlib` package or `Path` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`pathlib.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts)

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path("level1/level2/level3/")
>>> path.parts[-1]
'level3'
```

You can then append the `"/"` character if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like ultimately I'll have to add this `+ "/"` at the end

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for so long :)))

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [pathlib.name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name)

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path("level1/level2/level3/")
>>> path.name + "/"
'level3/'
```